# Populated DataGrid Won't Let App Close Gracefully

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm a bit new to the DataGrid control in WPF.  I've built a DataGrid into a UserControl, and wrapped that UserControl in a Window.  The DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="mDataGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.167,-0.077" Margin="-2.572,0,5.428,0" IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#1EA2A2E2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="389" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Term" Binding="{Binding Term}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Alternate" Binding="{Binding Alternate}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Document" Binding="{Binding Document}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="POS" Binding="{Binding POS}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Meaning" Binding="{Binding Meaning}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The C# code that I use to prep and display the control housing it:

```
            ObservableCollection<LexiconEntry> oc = new ObservableCollection<LexiconEntry>();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,LexiconEntry> kvp in lex.Entries)
            {
                LexiconEntry le=kvp.Value;
                oc.Add(le);
            }

            mDataGrid.ItemsSource = oc;
```

Now if I run the app without calling the above routine- meaning that the DataGrid is empty- everything closes properly.  If, on the other hand, I call the above routine to link an ItemSource to the DataGrid, the process remains running after I close all the windows.  I need to kill it with either the task manager or shift+F5 from within VS.  The windows close and I've traced through the Window_Closing and Window_Closed event handlers to verify this, but the process won't shut itself down.  I'm not quite sure how to see what's keeping it alive from within the debugger, but the only thing that causes this difference in whether or not the app exits gracefully is populating the DataGrid.

How can I fix this?  I've tried setting the DataGrid's ItemSource to null from within the OnClosing event of its parent window, but that hasn't helped.

Thanks!

Comment: Anything special happening in LexiconEntry ? How many items are we talking about?

Comment: Have you tried to pause the execution in the visual studio debugger and look which code is executing?

Comment: Could be a Leak. Try profiling the app.

Comment: I've tried profiling, but it's getting hung up in Lucene rather than the app, so I think it's a data formatting/memory issue in my app.  I'll get the PDBs for Lucene and see what I can see...

Answer (score 0):

Mike,
where are the LexiconEntry objects in the dictionary come from? How many pairs do you have in lex.Entries?

My suggestion is to try to create a new test class that looks like LexiconEntry and add as many of these as there are in lex.Entries. If things work well the problem lies on LexiconEntry objects in the dictionary.

Comment: I'm hand-creating the LexiconEntry objects.  Roughly 800 pairs.  I'll create some test classes and see what happens, thanks.